# How to add another instance of date picker in given code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have downloaded the complete zip of PopCalendarXP (Lite Edition) 9.8.309 from:

http://www.calendarxp.net/downloads.shtml

In the given folders various type of datepickers are there, but every page contains only one instance of date picker. I need to add two or more instances.

How can I change the code of HTML/JavaScript/CSS? I'm not able to do that.
Can anyone having a good command of jQuery and JavaScript
help me out?

Comment: @blasteralfred The HTML page that contains the date picker have only one instance of date picker....i want three instances of date picker in the same page......how can i do that?can any one go through the code and suggest additional code required in the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use JqueryUi DatePicker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Click View Source to show how it's done.

You can have as many DatePickers as you want

Comment: @vicor I really Appreaciate Your concern  but the date picker provider is much faster and is very lightweighted ..thats why

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having some text fields which get populated by datepicker. You may be giving them same ids. Try giving them different ids and write essential javascripts for each field. Using jquery ui datepicker is a good option.. [This link](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins-for-web-designers/) will be helpful to you containing various datepickers to choose from..

Comment: ya ya You are very right but I am cofused  about how to change IDs inthe available Code at the Above provided link by Me in the question

Comment: You may have a look at `ClassicDemo.htm` file included in demos